# EF Core is trying to insert a record with an existing primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core throws an exception:

> `System.InvalidOperationException`: 'The instance of entity type '`Appointment`' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 6}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

when trying to insert a model even though its primary key = 0.

**Appointment.cs**

```
public class Appointment
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public Appointment()
    {
    }

    public Appointment(Doctor doctor, Patient patient)
    {
        this.Doctor = doctor;
        this.Patient = patient;
        this.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Appointment(Doctor doctor, Patient patient, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        this.Doctor = doctor;
        this.Patient = patient;
        this.DateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

**How I create my Appointment instance:**

```
internal async Task AddAppointmentAsync(int doctorId, int patientId, DateTime dateTime)
{
    Doctor doctor = null;
    Patient patient = null;

    //Retrieve doctor from the db
    using (var doctorController = new DoctorController())
        await Task.Run(() => doctor = doctorController.GetDoctor(doctorId));
    if (doctor == null)
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Doctor with the specified id doesn't exist.");

    //Retrieve patient from the db
    using (var patientController = new PatientController())
        await Task.Run(() => patient = patientController.GetPatient(patientId));
    if (patient == null)
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Patient with the specified id doesn't exist.");

    //Create and insert appointment into the db
    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(doctor, patient, dateTime);
    using (_controller = new AppointmentController())
       await Task.Run(() => _controller.AddAppointment(appointment));
}
```

**Add appointment method**

```
public void AddAppointment(Appointment appointment)
{
    if (appointment == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appointment));
    if (appointment.Doctor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appointment.Doctor));
    if (appointment.Patient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appointment.Patient));

    Doctor doctor = appointment.Doctor;
    Patient patient = appointment.Patient;
    appointment.Doctor = null;
    appointment.Patient = null;

    this._context.Appointments.Add(appointment); 

    appointment.Doctor = doctor;
    appointment.Patient = patient;

    this._context.SaveChanges(); //Exception is thrown here
}
```

**My context:**

```
public class HospitalContext : DbContext
{
    private const string _connectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=ClientDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; private set; }
    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; private set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; private set; }
    public DbSet<MedicalRecord> MedicalRecords { get; private set; }

    public HospitalContext()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public HospitalContext(DbContextOptions<HospitalContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>()
            .HasMany(d => d.Appointments)
            .WithOne(a => a.Doctor)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>()
            .HasMany(w => w.WorkDays)
            .WithOne(a => a.Doctor)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Appointments)
            .WithOne(p => p.Patient)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
            .HasMany(p => p.MedicalRecords)
            .WithOne(m => m.Patient)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
            optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

        }
    }
}
```

What I'm passing to the method:

[image]

What I already have in my Appointments table:

[image]

**Update**

It looks like my table cannot contain multiple entries with the same `DoctorId` and `PatientId` foreign keys.
e.g.: Exception thrown when trying to add an entry with DoctorId=3, PatientId=1:

[image]

Comment: Your way from the "new Appointment" to the "DBset.Add" is missing. Maybe you add it twice ? Or you attach it already before ?

Comment: You need to make the field a Key.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entitykey?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Check what is in `doctor.Appointments` and `patient.Appointments` before calling `SaveChanges`.

Comment: You don't use any synchronization, so maybe before adding new entity to database, you are creating another one with the same ID (as it's not seen before adding the first indentity to database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning entity's `State` to `Added` before adding it to the context solved the issue.

**Add appointment method**

```
public void AddAppointment(Appointment appointment)
{
    if (appointment == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appointment));
    if (appointment.Doctor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appointment.Doctor));
    if (appointment.Patient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appointment.Patient));

    this._context.Entry(appointment).State = EntityState.Added;

    this._context.Appointments.Add(appointment);
    this._context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the entity you try to insert has the ID of an entity already in the database,
then very likely it IS the entity already in the database.

Maybe you do something like:

```
  var item = YourCollection.First();

  item.ID = 0;
  item.DateTime = DateTime.Now


  YourCollection.Add(item);
```

This is not going to work and will produce your behaviour. You have to physically create a new Item with `new Appointment()`

The same would also happen, if you insert it twice

```
  YourCollection.Add(item);
  YourCollection.Add(item);
```

That's rather not your case, cause you have the ID of an existing item assigned.

The tracking by ID is only one part of Entity Framework, but it also tracks the Entities by reference.

Comment: I think that's not what's going on. I added some code to clarify how I'm creating an `Appointment` instance.

Comment: SaveChanges will show any wrong insert/update/delete the first time, so it may be not related to your Insert here at all, it may happen something when loading the Doctor or the Patient, cause it's definitly involving this existing appointment somehow. You have nowhere Attach/Detach commands in your entire code ?

Comment: The only curious thing in your code are these 6 lines of  Copy/Assign/Reassing of  Doctor and Patient in the AddApointment method. I hope they are just experimental, they make absolutly no sense. You seem to have the idea, it makes a difference, setting properties before or after the Add.  
As a test - call the SaveChanges at the beginning of AddAppointment. If the context ist unmodified - as expected - it will do nothing. If the error is thrown already here - than the error has nothing to do with AddAppointment.